# jQuery equivalent of YUI StyleSheet Utility?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, yui, stylesheet

Does jQuery - or one of it's plugins - have equivalent functionality to the [YUI StyleSheet Utility?](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/stylesheet/)

"The StyleSheet Utility is capable of creating new stylesheets from scratch as well as modifying the existing stylesheets held as properties of  elements sourced from the same domain or any inline  elements."

This (I'm fairly sure) is creating and modifying CSS *stylesheets* themselves **not** looping through the DOM and changing element's `style` property (as the `jQuery.css()` method does).

I think this technique has the potential to significantly change the way a lot user interface related Javascript is written so would be interested to hear about any other libraries where it's been implemented too.

Comment: I have my doubts on it's abilities to change UI. You can store unused CSS rules in the style-sheet and simply modify the class attribute. It's never really necessary to loop through style properties.

Comment: But for instance this opens up the possibility of calculating values for style properties in JS and applying the changes with proper CSS rules rather than using style properties.

Comment: Ah! Maybe I'm not clear when I say UI - by UI I meant "user interface" rather than "jQuery UI". Edited question for clarity.

Comment: I know there was a jQuery plugin that let you alter the CSS o a page exactly the way you said. I don't remember its name though.

Comment: @edeverett I guess I can see how it would be useful in that instance, and I did know you meant regular UI :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found a couple that look like they do similar things. I haven't tested them. jQuery.Rule looks to be pretty good though

[**jQuery.Rule**](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/11/jqueryrule.html) by Ariel Flesler

> This plugin allows quick creation/manipulation of CSS Rules, in a "jQuery-way". It includes features like chaining, iteration using each, selectors with context.

[**GlobalStylesheet**](http://www.burnbright.co.nz/globalstylesheet-jquery-plugin/) by Jeremy Lea

> Enables CSS modification that uses a 'global' stylesheet, rather than inline CSS. This is particularly handy for modifying CSS styles that you want to remain persistent until a page is refreshed again.

Comment: Yes, jQuery.Rule was the plugin I was talking about.

Comment: One of these links led me to this page http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript where the raw techniques are discussed in depth. Good stuff.

Comment: I've used all these suggestions, "GlobalStylesheet" works the best so far

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. YUI is the avant garde in this matter.

However I fully expect there to be something similar being made in the coming weeks(months), as the methodology that YUI is using does not seem to be unreplicable and considering how useful and important this feature is.

Maybe study YUI's method and make a plugin yourself?

Edit: Looks like I'm wrong. This is why you never post negatives like this. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll certainly be investigating how YUI get it to work but I think I'll leave writing the plugin to someone with more skills than myself.