# can jquery manipulate the global css definition of the document?

Tags: jquery, css

i'm trying to make a checkbox that will hide a specific css class when clicked, but i also want this effect to apply to all future objects that get that specific class.

for example: i have 2 divs:

divA is of class abc

divB has no class

i want the checkbox to hide all divs of class `abc`, this is easy, using `$(".abc").hide()`. but the problem is that if another part of the site made divB of class `abc` later on, then it won't be hidden. because the jquery code would've only applied to divA at the time.

what i'm trying to do is make the checkbox manipulate the global css definition of the document. so when the user clicks the checkbox, i would change the `abc` class to be hidden, and later whenever any div joins that class, it would be hidden.

is this possible in jquery?

Comment: Here is a similar question with a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079237/jquery-equivalent-of-yui-stylesheet-utility

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would probably handle this by having your checkbox add and remove a class form the <body> element:

```
$('body').toggleClass('hideABC');
```

And have the following CSS:

```
body.hideABC div.abc { display:none; }
body div.abc { display:block; }
```

So, if elsewhere in your page a <div> gets the '.abc' class added to it, then it will take on the first CSS rule and be hidden.

Comment: To my mind this is a much better (and in particular simpler) approach than the alternatives.  Why so few votes?  Is there some flaw with this approach?

Comment: That's really clever and seems like it would be much more reliable cross-browser than trying to add new rules into the stylesheet. I can't think of any downsides to that approach.

Comment: This looks simple now, but it would become a whole lot more complex to work with once you started applying the class programmatically to data rendered from AJAX polling, for example.

Answer (score 33):

You can use the [`insertRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`addRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa358796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (when necessary) methods to add new rules to the `.abc` selector. That should affect anything in the future that gets that class applied to it.

```
var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0],
    selector = ".abc", rule = "{color: red}";

if (stylesheet.insertRule) {
    stylesheet.insertRule(selector + rule, stylesheet.cssRules.length);
} else if (stylesheet.addRule) {
    stylesheet.addRule(selector, rule, -1);
}
```

There is a jQuery plugin for this also: `$.rule()`; It's available at https://github.com/flesler/jquery.rule

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though I should mention that this code will only work in IE. My app is a greasemonkey script, so after spending hours looking online, it turns out for firefox the syntax should be: 

    document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(".abc { display:none; }", 0);

Comment: Doesn't work in modern Firefox. You get: "Error: The operation is insecure."

Comment: This method is only for IE, it appears to have no support outside of it and is not even mentioned on caniuse.com: http://caniuse.com/#search=insertRule

Comment: @this.lau_ `insertRule` is supported by [all major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule#Browser_compatibility).