# jquery add css declarations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

Is it possible with jquery to add new style declarations?

For example, pass:

```
{ "body": { "font-size": "12px" }, "table": { "xyz": "123" } }
```

etc etc

to a function I don't know without having to select those elements and do it like this:

```
$('body').css({"font-size": "12px"});
$('table').css({"xyz": "123"});
```

And second part of the question, is it possible to set css for the :hover pseudo class with jquery or do I need to use the .hover() function? If possible I just want css applied and not have to deal with on mouse in / out functions.

```
$('#element').find('a.thumbnail:hover').css({'background-color': '#efefef' });
```

does not work.

Thanks,
Wesley

Comment: See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348741/can-jquery-manipulate-the-global-css-definition-of-the-document

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can alter the stylesheet itself with pure javascript through the `document.stylesheets` collection. see more here: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domstylesheets

You can also use the jQuery plugin jRule to accomplish the same results: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/11/jqueryrule.html

Answer (score 4):

**Answer to part 1:**

You would have to define a function to do that - try something like this:

```
function styleit(json)
{
    //loop through the json
    $.each(item, function(i, style){
      //apply styles
      $(i).css(styles);
    }
}
```

---

**Answer to part 2:**

I would put the css declaration in a class like:

```
.active a.thumbnail:hover { background-color: #efefef; }
```

Then use javascript to toggle the class in a parent element's context

```
$('#element').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you are correctly adding styles to the `body` and `table` tags.

For the second part, this solution, while using `.hover()` seems to be a easier solution:

```
$('#element').hover(function() {
    $(this).css({'background-color': '#efefef' });
});
```

Comment: hover() has 2 functions, background will not revert back.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have always just used a callback and didn't actually know that it wouldn't revert back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('a.thumbnail').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#efefef'});
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css({'background-color':'normal-color'});
    }
);
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/jfhpg/1/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do it by selecting the dom element only. Also in order to set the hover styles you have to either set the styles using css or add/remove class names.

Comment: @Phil - He is asking whether it is possible to do it the way he wants. I answered it is not possible he has to do the way he is doing. I think I shouldn't get down vote for this. I didnt answer anything wrong here.

Comment: You didn't answer it wrong, but it's a complete waste of an answer. I'll remove the down vote if you edit it...