# How to make the effects of jQuery's $(element).css() persistent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For example, with a font-size switcher/button, if I use

```
    $('#container p').css('font-size', '24px');
```

it works as expected, but if I later add paragraph elements to the container (via ajax, etc), they are not styled with the updated font-size. I am aware that this is the intended behavior of the `.css()` method. I am simply asking:

**What's the proper approach to changing a style for a CSS selector, and making those styles persistent?**

Comment: I am selecting Alexsander Akers' answer, with this **caveat**: In the case where you need persistence for a style, and all of the elements *may not be* within the same container, adding/removing a stylesheet object may be the best choice. **However**, in cases where all of the elements are within the same parent, a style/class definition should be created and toggled on the **parent/container**, via `toggleClass()` or `addClass()`/`removeClass()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, well, when you perform that command, it styles all `p` elements in `#container`. If you want it to be permanent, you could create a `<style />` element and add the CSS stylings there.

---

To elaborate, you could do something like this:

```
$(document.head).append('<style>#container p{font-size: 24px;}</style>');
```

Comment: Is this acceptable in cases where the user may toggle styles?

Comment: I suppose the better practice is to create multiple style rules, and simply toggle the classes on the parent/container element. I just thought that jQuery might have something that handled a global rule change for you. Thanks!

Comment: Work for me with    $('<style type="text/css"></style>')
        .appendTo('head')
        .html('div.myClass { background:yellow; }');

Answer (score 2):

What jQuery does in that line is equivalent to:

```
<div id='container'>
  <p style='font-size:24px'>a</p>
  <p style='font-size:24px'>b</p>
  <p style='font-size:24px'>c</p>
</div>
```

For your particular case I'd get one of the stylesheets present in the document, like this:

```
var stylesheets = document.styleSheets
```

Which returns an array of [styleSheet objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/stylesheet) that contain the [insertRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/stylesheet.insertRule) method, which you can use to add your new (permanent) css rule.

Cheers!

Comment: Note that `insertRule()` is Firefox specific.  Try the [jQuery.Rule plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/11/jqueryrule.html) for cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: @Orbling No it's not, I'm using Chrome and I can see the method

Comment: @Orbling, Ok I cannot argue that even if I don't have IE in my machine. Everything is badly broken on that browser

Comment: LOL, well most things are a pain on it.  Particularly when it comes to JS.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add the style directly w/ JavaScript, but you can however do this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="paragraph1">blah</div>
  <div id="paragraph2">you</div>
</div>
```

and

```
$("#wrapper").css...
```

This way any paragraph you add to the wrapper will have the new font size...

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing, for my particular problem, because all of the elements were within the same container. However, instead of using `.css()`, I used `.toggleClass()` or `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` on the parent, and created a matching style rule for children of `parent.class { foo: bar; }`

Answer (score 1):

Well you are adding style to exiting elements only, there is no way for jquery to know about the new elements.

Comment: I agree. Was hoping it came across as a clear example of what works, so that my intended effect would be clear. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you are destroying the element upon which you have the style.

If you are bringing in via AJAX a replacement for `#container`, then all of the content will get destroyed and replaced with the new content.  All of the `<p>` tags you added the style to will no longer exist, and it will need to be repeated on the newer entry.

What you could try is creating a [class definition on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079237/jquery-equivalent-of-yui-stylesheet-utility).

Comment: Actually, I'm appending new paragraph elements to the existing container. The new elements aren't styled.

Comment: @anonymous coward: Similar principle then, the new elements coming in still were not present when you initially made the modification.  `$('#container p')` corresponds to the time of calling, not for all time.  Anything added later, will need doing again.

Comment: Yes, I meant to clarify but left out that "It is [the new elements]...". I will probably just create multiple class rules, and toggle classes as necessary.

Comment: @anonymous coward: That's what I tend to do.