# set image source using css only

Tags: html, css

I'd like to load images and their contents dynamically from a css file. I know I can set the background-image attribute for divs, but how can I achieve something similar for images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the src of the img to a transparent gif and set the background image of the img just like you would a div but that's a bit of a hack. You can change the src attribute of an image very easily using javascript:

html:

```
<img id="asdf" src="1.gif"  />
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById("asdf").setAttribute("src","2.gif");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

The `<img>` element holds content. The specifics of that content aren't something that can, or should, be described on the presentation layer.

Comment: I see, is there any way to read a content of a css file using jquery?

Comment: There appear to be plugins for it that provide a cross browser method of accessing the stylesheet ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079237/jquery-equivalent-of-yui-stylesheet-utility ), however, given the content, I think I feel kinda ill now.

Comment: Quentin's answer here obviously does not answer the question asked, but it does invite the OP to take a more enlightened approach to web authoring.  Quentin's answer would be more effective if he linked to a nice writeup describing the ideal separation of content and presentation.