# Is it possible to set CSS properties of .element:before or .element:after via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I set CSS properties of .anyclass:before or .anyclass:after via javascript?

Comment: Do you want to add it as a general rule to the page?

Comment: `:before` and `:after` are not properties, they are CSS selectors. Therefore you cannot set them on some element, you can only add rules with such selectors to a stylesheet.

Comment: :( they are so useful though. setting properties on them programmatically would be wonderful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

`:before` and `:after` are not properties, [they are CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after). Therefore you cannot set them on some element, you can only add rules with such selectors to a stylesheet.

If you want to add DOM nodes before or after all elements that match a given selector with jQuery, you can use the [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) and [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) methods respectively.

If you want to add CSS rules to the current page, you can use the [DOM level 2 CSSStyleSheet interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleSheet). A minimal example would look like this:

```
// Note: this is sample code. Do not use it blindly in your own page.
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(".foo:before { /* something */ }", 0);
```

See the MDN documentation for [`insertRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) for more example code.

Answer (score 0):

Only by [modifying the stylesheet itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079237/jquery-equivalent-of-yui-stylesheet-utility). Since they aren't real elements you cannot modify their inline style (because they don't have any).