# How to apply this method to all future matching elements as well?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following javascript/jquery snippet applies a css to all currently matchicng elements in the DOM.

```
$('.centeredByJquery').each(function(){
    $(this).css({'margin-left': -parseInt($(this).css('width'))/2,
                'left':'50%',
                'margin-top': -parseInt($(this).css('height'))/2,
                'top':'50%'});
})
```

How do I apply this method to all future matching elements as well ?

Comment: Are you going to be adding more elements with the `centeredByJquery` class?

Comment: You can't set the style property of an element that does'nt exist yet, it's simply something that can't be delegated to a parent, and you would have to insert a style tag into the head instead, or figure out a way to do the same thing with regular CSS.

Comment: Simply add the class `centeredByJquery` when you add new elements.

Comment: @tymeJV: yep when updated by ajax

Comment: By not using `.css()`

Comment: From what I understand is he wants to use this as a basis for changing other elements in his site. Which he would probably need to turn this into a variable function that he can call.

Comment: You can modify `document.styleSheets` to change style definitions dynamically. jQuery doesn't have an interface to this, just use plain Javascript.

Comment: please note I m forced to specify css rule using javascript as I need to set dynamically calculated values to `margin-*`

Comment: You need to run said code in the ajax success either directly, or by calling a function that does it. There is no automagical way to run code when x element is available that works in all browsers.

Comment: @KevinB: ohk.. I was expecting that somthing like `on()` or `live()` that do apply to future matching elements..

Comment: I think the answers here may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079237/jquery-equivalent-of-yui-stylesheet-utility

Comment: But `on` and `live` need to be attached to specific events.

Comment: .on and .live require an event, your code above doesn't happen on an event.

Comment: Can you post your AJAX call?

Comment: @Barmar,  Kevin: yes I got that!

Comment: I wrote a micro-framework once that injects into native DOM manipulation elements, but I never tested browser compatibility. Maybe you can expand upon it, should it be necessary... It's purpose was to react to new elements within the site that have not been added through AJAX yet you do not have control of how and when they are added, like through other plugins. You can find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Derija93/Z8cDj/). Maybe it helps.

Comment: The answer is *"When you update the DOM, you call the method that runs this code!"*

Answer (score 0):

You can't.. The only way to do that is using an interval:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.centeredByJquery').each(function(){
        $(this).css({'margin-left': -parseInt($(this).css('width'))/2,
                    'left':'50%',
                    'margin-top': -parseInt($(this).css('height'))/2,
                    'top':'50%'});
    })
},1000);
```

But it is a terrible idea..

If you know WHEN a new element is inserted, you can just call a function to center that element.